# How can I record the date/time when a new row is added?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to add a date value when a new row is added in Google spreadsheet.

I have seen the script on Add a 'creation date' value when a new line is edited, but I was not able to modify the code to my needs.

Which changes do I need to do in that script?

Referred https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53378/how-can-i-record-the-date-time-when-a-new-row-is-added/53379#53379

Below is what i did. Tools--> Script editor-->Pasted the code-->Resources-->Current project's triggers-->Chickhere to add one now-->then selected onModification, From spreadsheet, Onchange then clicked on Save-->then I clicked on onModication and then fillEmptyRows Below error displayed. TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code"). TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of undefined. (line 9, file "Code"). I have checked by adding one new row its not coming. I have not changed to New googlesheet.

Answer (score 0):

The code you refer to works perfectly... just tested now.

did you get the authorization request when you activated (saved) the trigger in the ressource menu ?

If not then repeat every step carefully and just test it by 'insert a new row' from the 'insert' menu.
[image]

save this setup

[image]

accept the authorization

[image]

and you're done, return to the SS and insert a new row.

Comment: thank you so much, it is working in my different gmail id logins...In my current id If I create new Google Spreadsheet I am not able to see Script gallery in Tools, Protect Sheet, Hidden sheet, Email as attachment are disabled that the reason it was not working.I have to fix this